# when is the client configuration file mqclient.ini used?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I've got a question with the MQ client configuration file mqclient.ini.

If i have one MQ JAVA application which put msg to queue of remote MQ server in another box through TCP， does that java application search mqclient.ini locally when connectting to MQ Server? Or will it even go find that mqclient.ini file in remote MQ Server? since there is one default such file under MQ sever data directory, like /var/mqm

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

MQ Client libraries use the mqclient.ini file located on the local server. They don't use the one on the remote server. The mqclient.ini file on the remote server will be used by MQ applications running on there.

Comment: thanks @Shashi. so that means my MQ JAVA application uses its local mqclient.ini only, am i right?